# react-native project Type

Tags: android, react-native, adb, mobile-application

I've cina device whit android lollipop 5.1 i can create and  run in device this type of  react-native  project

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

But if i try to create and  run in device this type of  react-native  project

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

cant run it in device get this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: 
com.android.ddmlib.InstallExc
eption: Failed to install all
```

Comment: Have you enabled usb debugging? Followed all the steps in the docs for running on device?

Comment: In addition to Rob's questions: What's the output of `adb devices`?

Comment: i solved the problem but have an other problem

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem changing   build:gradle version to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

and gradle to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

now i must un the app in the device whit

```
react-native run-android  and  react-native start
```

but cant have live reload update and i must give every app change this command

```
react-native run-android
```

how can solve this and have live reload update